# information about the configuration of UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i would like to know configuration about UITextField standard please

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender 
{
    UITextField * textfieldToAdd = [[[UITextField alloc] init] autorelease];
    // ... configuration code for textfield ...
    [self.view addSubview:textfieldToAdd];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code from Apple's example UICatalog

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Text Fields

- (UITextField *)textFieldNormal
{
    if (textFieldNormal == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(kLeftMargin, 8.0, kTextFieldWidth, kTextFieldHeight);
        textFieldNormal = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        textFieldNormal.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
        textFieldNormal.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        textFieldNormal.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
        textFieldNormal.placeholder = @"<enter text>";
        textFieldNormal.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        textFieldNormal.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;    // no auto correction support

        textFieldNormal.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;   // use the default type input method (entire keyboard)
        textFieldNormal.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

        textFieldNormal.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;  // has a clear 'x' button to the right

        textFieldNormal.tag = kViewTag;     // tag this control so we can remove it later for recycled cells

        textFieldNormal.delegate = self;    // let us be the delegate so we know when the keyboard's "Done" button is pressed

        // Add an accessibility label that describes what the text field is for.
        [textFieldNormal setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"NormalTextField", @"")];
    }   
    return textFieldNormal;
}

- (UITextField *)textFieldRounded
{
    if (textFieldRounded == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(kLeftMargin, 8.0, kTextFieldWidth, kTextFieldHeight);
        textFieldRounded = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        textFieldRounded.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textFieldRounded.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        textFieldRounded.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
        textFieldRounded.placeholder = @"<enter text>";
        textFieldRounded.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        textFieldRounded.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;   // no auto correction support

        textFieldRounded.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        textFieldRounded.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

        textFieldRounded.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; // has a clear 'x' button to the right

        textFieldRounded.tag = kViewTag;        // tag this control so we can remove it later for recycled cells

        textFieldRounded.delegate = self;   // let us be the delegate so we know when the keyboard's "Done" button is pressed

        // Add an accessibility label that describes what the text field is for.
        [textFieldRounded setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"RoundedTextField", @"")];
    }
    return textFieldRounded;
}

- (UITextField *)textFieldSecure
{
    if (textFieldSecure == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(kLeftMargin, 8.0, kTextFieldWidth, kTextFieldHeight);
        textFieldSecure = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        textFieldSecure.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
        textFieldSecure.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        textFieldSecure.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
        textFieldSecure.placeholder = @"<enter password>";
        textFieldSecure.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        textFieldSecure.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        textFieldSecure.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;    
        textFieldSecure.secureTextEntry = YES;  // make the text entry secure (bullets)

        textFieldSecure.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;  // has a clear 'x' button to the right

        textFieldSecure.tag = kViewTag;     // tag this control so we can remove it later for recycled cells

        textFieldSecure.delegate = self;    // let us be the delegate so we know when the keyboard's "Done" button is pressed

        // Add an accessibility label that describes what the text field is for.
        [textFieldSecure setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"SecureTextField", @"")];
    }
    return textFieldSecure;
}

- (UITextField *)textFieldLeftView
{
    if (textFieldLeftView == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(kLeftMargin, 8.0, kTextFieldWidth, kTextFieldHeight);
        textFieldLeftView = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        textFieldLeftView.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;
        textFieldLeftView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        textFieldLeftView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
        textFieldLeftView.placeholder = @"<enter text>";
        textFieldLeftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        textFieldLeftView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        textFieldLeftView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  

        textFieldLeftView.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;    // has a clear 'x' button to the right

        textFieldLeftView.tag = kViewTag;       // tag this control so we can remove it later for recycled cells

        // Add an accessibility label that describes the text field.
        [textFieldLeftView setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"CheckMarkIcon", @"")];

        textFieldLeftView.leftView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_check.png"]];
        textFieldLeftView.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

        textFieldLeftView.delegate = self;  // let us be the delegate so we know when the keyboard's "Done" button is pressed
    }
    return textFieldLeftView;
}
```

Go through the reference doc for UITextField Class also try to read UITextFieldDelegate. Look for the different tasks that can be performed and see the methods, properties available for it. And use it according to your requirement.

Comment: how to make a textField moves when I press on it I can change position freely in sight